# Preventing other elements from event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below code is a simple version of my code. When I mouse over on `#realWrapper` then the thick border show up in my code.

The problem is that when I mouse over  on `a` tag and `.btn`, which are inside the sibling div with `#wrapper`, `mouseout` event of `#realWrapper` occurs!

So, If I add `background-color: #000` css to `#realWrapper` then it is fine, but the contents of `#wrapper` covered by `#realWrapper`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#realWrapper").mouseover(function(e) {
    $(e.target).css("border-color", "#f00");
  }).mouseout(function(e) {
    $(e.target).css("border-color", "#000");
  });
});
```

```css
#item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#realWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 10;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

a {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item">
  <div id="realWrapper"></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div>
      <a href="#">Hi abcdefg!</a>
      <div class="btn">
        OK
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to prevent event of other elements, I select, from event occurring?

Thanks.

(Plus, This not happen in IE10. The browser I checked is IE8)

Comment: The issue is not clear

Comment: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` google `stopPropagation()`

Comment: @KiranDash I cover an div with same size and z-index: 10. And the wrapper has no background-color. When I mouse over on the elements under wrapper, the mouseout event of wrapper is occurred.

Comment: @zer00ne sorry, I'm checking it in IE8. As I know `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` do not work in IE8.

Comment: @wallah. thanks for explaining better. The solution to your problem will be adjusting the position accordingly. check my answer below

Comment: @wallah IE8, 9, and 10 haven't been supported for the last 2 years. IE8 has a 0.21% use globally.

Comment: @zer00ne I know. But we always consider it. In my case, I should consider the schools that still have old version computers and also browsers. They rarely change or upgrade their computers. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML and JS when any event occurred in elemnet it propogates to parent element. you can retrict it by using `e.preventDefault()` method of event object also you can `return false` from that event function of sub element

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#realWrapper > * ").mouseover(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }).mouseout(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    $("#realWrapper").mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).css("border-color", "#f00");
    }).mouseout(function(e) {
        $(this).css("border-color", "#000");
    });
});
```

```css
#item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#realWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 10;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

a {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item">
  <div id="realWrapper"></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div>
      <a href="#">Hi abcdefg!</a>
      <div class="btn">
        OK
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also think about it in another ways. This is very powerful but I worry about efficient of `*` selector.  In my code the number of elements in `#wrapper` are three. But in real code there are many elements and also many `#item`s. But thank you for yor answer!

Comment: @wallah, this is my pleasure to share my knowledge with you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent other elements by testing `e.target` (for example : `$(e.target).is('#wrapper *')`.
However, this will not help you, because the problem is not other elements : You event fires when the mouse leaves #realWrapper, and that will happen when you move onto #wrapper.

I'm guessing we don't have the whole information, but why don't you put #wrapper inside #realWrapper ? That way you could use `e.stopPropagation()` or `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: If I do this, when I mouse over on `#realWrapper`, the descendant of it fire event. And it will be difficult to handdle it.

Comment: Then you can use `preventDefault()` or `stopPropagation()` coupled with `e.target`. But at least the mouseout event will not fire. Other solution (which I have done as rarely as possible because it quickly becomes a mess) is to declare a custom event and trigger it yourself, for example onmouseenter on other elements....

Answer (score 1):

Because you have applied `z-index:10` and `position:absolute` to the `#realWrapper` div, thats why your `#realWrapper` div coming over the `#wrapper` div

Try to add `position:relative` and higher `z-index` value to `#wrapper` div

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#realWrapper")
    .mouseover(function(e) {
      $(e.target).css("border-color", "#f00");
    })
    .mouseout(function(e) {
      $(e.target).css("border-color", "#000");
    });
});
```

```css
#item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#realWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11;
  border:1px solid lime;
}

a {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item">
  <div id="realWrapper"></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div>
      <a href="#">Hi abcdefg!</a>
      <div class="btn">
        OK
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your answer, if I mouse over on descendant of `#wrapper`, the `#realWrapper`'s mouseout event occur...

Comment: @wallah In the above answer I have removed the `height:100px` from the `#wrapper`....I have added a border to see the difference...Check updated..!

Comment: What I really want to do is when I mouse over green box and it's element in your code, the `#realWrapper`'s border still red. But if `#wrapper`'s z-index is more than `#realWrapper`, the `#realWrapper`'s border change when move mouse in green box. But still thank you for your answer!

Comment: @wallah If you want that then what is the problem in your code...?

Comment: In IE8, not others, althoug I wrap other elements with higher z-index div, the browser capture the event which occur on elements under wrapper. But in Chrome, IE >8, it does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem will be adjusting the position accordingly. Add position relative and set a `z-index` higher than the `realWrapper`. I have modified the `width` and `heights` of wrapper and `realWrapper` so that you can see the difference.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#realWrapper").mouseover(function(e) {
    $(e.target).css("border-color", "#f00");
  }).mouseout(function(e) {
    $(e.target).css("border-color", "#000");
  });
});
```

```css
#item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#realWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 10;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

a {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item">
  <div id="realWrapper"></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div>
      <a href="#">Hi abcdefg!</a>
      <div class="btn">
        OK
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the negative vote? Please do comment while adding a negative vote so that the mistake can be corrected.

Comment: I don't know who do this. I'm trying your answer. thank for your answer!

Comment: What I really want to do is when I mouse over yellow box and it's element in your code, the `#realWrapper`'s border still red. But if `#wrapper`'s z-index is more than `#realWrapper`, the `#realWrapper`'s border change when move mouse in yellow box. But still thank you for your answer!

Comment: I don't understand. So you want it to stay red when hovering over the inner wrapper also? In that case just use your code that you have posted with your question. That is working exactly like that

Comment: yes it is. But not in IE8. When I use my code in IE10 and Chrome it is fine as you said. But not in IE8. IE8 capture every events of elements under wrapper.